# Python 3 Cosine Nearest Neighbor Format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am working on some data mining self-learning from a free online resource I found. Basically I got a csv file with a bunch of names, movie titles, and what each person rated it. I'm trying to get the K-Nearest Neighbor from it using a cosine metric but I can't get the output to look not awful. Heres what I have so far for the code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors as nn

df =  pd.read_csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MSBm3M6YmaLf0aiJCvkvrPsIJB2pPuBwse5ylnzEHRI/pub?gid=639849687&single=true&output=csv",index_col='Unnamed: 0')

df = df.fillna(0)

nn([df], metric = 'cosine')
```

Pretty simple to do! Except my output looks like this:

```
NearestNeighbors(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='cosine',
     metric_params=None, n_jobs=1,
     n_neighbors=[                      Patrick C  Heather  Bryan  
Patrick T  Thomas  aaron  \
Alien                       NaN      NaN    2.0        NaN     5.0    
4.0
Avatar                      4.0      5.0    5.0        4.0     2.0    NaN
Blade Runner                5.0      NaN    NaN        N...
You Got Mail           NaN  2.0      2.0   1.0      2.0      NaN   2.0

[25 rows x 25 columns]],
     p=2, radius=1.0)
```

Its messy and doesn't even show all the data. I tried casting it into an array but I go the error message "'ABCMeta' object does not support indexing"

I'm fairly new to Python, I can do a few basic things but I am no expert. I was hoping someone could help nudge me in the direction to help clean this up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear what your desired output looks like. However, you should first instantiate the class and then use the `fit()` method.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors as nn

df =  pd.read_csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MSBm3M6YmaLf0aiJCvkvrPsIJB2pPuBwse5ylnzEHRI/pub?gid=639849687&single=true&output=csv",index_col='Unnamed: 0')
df = df.fillna(0)
model = nn(metric = 'cosine')
model.fit(df.values)
```

Now `model` is a fitted object that you can use to find the K-neighbors of any new point, which is probably your goal. See the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors).